# Please check my demonstration of de l'hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

I have demostrate the de l'hopital theorem but in some steps I'm not 100% sure;

The theorem I demostrate is for:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow a+}  \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=L \implies\lim_{x\rightarrow a+}  \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} $ with $ g,f \rightarrow \infty $

Here I report only the demostration not the hypothesis.

**Demostration**

For a fixed $\epsilon \ \exists \ x_1 \ | \ \forall \ \xi \in (a,x_1) \ L-\epsilon<\frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)}<L+\epsilon $

For each x $\in$ $(a,x_1)$ for cauchy theorem$\frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)}=\frac{f(x)-f(x_1)}{g(x)-g(x_1)}$; So :
 $L-\epsilon<\frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)}=\frac{f(x)-f(x_1)}{g(x)-g(x_1)}<L+\epsilon $  $\\\\$ with $x<\xi<x_1$

$L-\epsilon<\frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)}=\frac{f(x)(1-\frac{f(x_1)}{f(x)})}{g(x)(1-\frac{f(g_1)}{g(x)})}<L+\epsilon $

I call $\beta=\frac{f(x)(1-\frac{f(x_1)}{f(x)})}{g(x)(1-\frac{f(g_1)}{g(x)})}$ and I assume  that $f,g\rightarrow\infty$ :

I consider the same $\epsilon$ used at the beginning so $ \exists \ \delta \ | \ \forall \ x \in (a,a+\delta) \ 1-\epsilon<\beta<1+\epsilon $

So for $a<x<min\ \left \{ a+\delta,x_1 \right \} \ $: $(L-\epsilon)(1-\epsilon)<\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}<(L+\epsilon)(1+\epsilon) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks right.

In terms of proof-writing, I would say the following:

- First, make sure you always state $\epsilon > 0$ rather than just $\epsilon$.
- It is better to use more words and less symbols. It drastically improves the readability of the proof.

Comment: Your second point is so important and many books highly disregard the use of English words in favor of symbolism (so sad). +1

Comment: Thanks, so I have to work on use more words. But the demostration is it completely right?

Comment: @MarcoIntini It looks right.